# Re-create cosmos DB by using script

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I have an existing cosmos DB tied to a particular account.

My question is if I can create the same CosmosDB in another account by using script deployment.

I've investigated that is possible to create resoruces by using Azure Resource Manager, but not sure how can I get the template of the existing CosmosDB.

Also Is there a way to get the JSON script of the existing CosmosDB ?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to migrate Cosmosdb from one account to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437442/how-to-migrate-cosmosdb-from-one-account-to-another)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have a schema as such, you have settings and indexes configuration and other assets.

To migrate the data have a look at this tool

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data

Once the data is migrated just copy and paste any indexes definitions and other assets such as procedures.

You may need to ramp up the RUs during the migration.

### Some examples on how to use the tool :

#### Migrate data from one Azure Cosmos DB collection to another Azure Cosmos DB collections

```
dt.exe /s:CosmosDB /s.ConnectionString:"AccountEndpoint=<CosmosDB Endpoint>;AccountKey=<CosmosDB Key>;Database=<CosmosDB Database>;" /s.Collection:TEColl /t:CosmosDBBulk /t.ConnectionString:" AccountEndpoint=<CosmosDB Endpoint>;AccountKey=<CosmosDB Key>;Database=<CosmosDB Database>;" /t.Collection:TESessions /t.CollectionThroughput:2500
```

#### Migrate data from multiple Azure Cosmos DB collections to a single Azure Cosmos DB collection

```
dt.exe /s:CosmosDB /s.ConnectionString:"AccountEndpoint=<CosmosDB Endpoint>;AccountKey=<CosmosDB Key>;Database=<CosmosDB Database>;" /s.Collection:comp1|comp2|comp3|comp4 /t:CosmosDBBulk /t.ConnectionString:"AccountEndpoint=<CosmosDB Endpoint>;AccountKey=<CosmosDB Key>;Database=<CosmosDB Database>;" /t.Collection:singleCollection /t.CollectionThroughput:2500
```

#### Export an Azure Cosmos DB collection to a JSON file

```
dt.exe /s:CosmosDB /s.ConnectionString:"AccountEndpoint=<CosmosDB Endpoint>;AccountKey=<CosmosDB Key>;Database=<CosmosDB Database>;" /s.Collection:StoresSub /t:JsonFile /t.File:StoresExport.json /t.Overwrite /t.CollectionThroughput:2500
```